# SELinux is preventing /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox from write access on which file?

Tags: fedora, chrome, selinux

I keep getting the following error ever since upgrading to Chrome `google-chrome-stable-42.0.2311.90-1.x86_64`.

> SELinux is preventing /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox from write
>   access on the file .

I have not installed any custom plugins or modified my Chrome settings. Various search on Google turns up [bug reports being closed as not a bug](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1211799), and instructions on how to bypass SELinux by applying custom policy.

The SELinux troubleshooter suggested the following:

```
SELinux is preventing /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox from write access on the file .

*****  Plugin chrome (98.5 confidence) suggests   ****************************

If you want to use the plugin package
Then you must turn off SELinux controls on the Chrome plugins.
Do
# setsebool -P unconfined_chrome_sandbox_transition 0

*****  Plugin catchall (2.46 confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that chrome-sandbox should be allowed write access on the  file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# grep chrome-sandbox /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
# semodule -i mypol.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                unconfined_u:unconfined_r:chrome_sandbox_t:s0-s0:c
                              0.c1023
Target Context                unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1
                              023
Target Objects                 [ file ]
Source                        chrome-sandbox
Source Path                   /opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          fqdn
Source RPM Packages           google-chrome-stable-42.0.2311.90-1.x86_64
Target RPM Packages           
Policy RPM                    selinux-policy-3.12.1-197.fc20.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     fqdn
Platform                      Linux fqdn 3.19.4-100.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP
                              Mon Apr 13 21:46:59 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64
Alert Count                   68
First Seen                    2015-04-25 18:15:53
Last Seen                     2015-04-30 20:51:59
Local ID                      ab14f

Raw Audit Messages
type=AVC msg=audit(123.456:300): avc:  denied  { write } for  pid=3642 comm="chrome-sandbox" name="oom_adj" dev="proc" ino=52951 scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:chrome_sandbox_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=file permissive=0


type=SYSCALL msg=audit(123.456:300): arch=x86_64 syscall=openat success=no exit=EACCES a0=3 a1=402138 a2=1 a3=0 items=0 ppid=3480 pid=3642 auid=1000 uid=1000 gid=1000 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=(none) ses=1 comm=chrome-sandbox exe=/opt/google/chrome/chrome-sandbox subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:chrome_sandbox_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)

Hash: chrome-sandbox,chrome_sandbox_t,unconfined_t,file,write
```

I do not quite agree with the recommendation to turn off SELinux controls on Chrome Plugins. I also do not know what write access on file `.` means. Is it current folder of chrome-sandbox? I tried searching for the inode `52591`, but could not find the file.

Can anyone explain what is the problem and how this issue can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

It is a regression (previously fixed bug that's come up again) in Chromium / Chrome. The Google developers seem to be in no hurry to fix it, or even acknowledge that it's their bug (sigh).

Current bug ID: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=477329

Original closed bug: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=41853

Comment: The bugs describe error with "*'write' accesses on the file oom_score_adj.*". I don't see clearly how it relates to OP's issue.

Answer (score -1):

```
$ grep chrome /var/log/audit/audit.log | audit2allow -M mypol
$ semodule -i mypol.pp
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L SE. Don't just enter command, also tell how this command will work to solve the issue.

Comment: The question is not about how to add allow rule, the original error message even already suggests `setsebool -P unconfined_chrome_sandbox_transition 0` to enable allow rules.